# Magento 2.1.6 - update cron.php permission denied

Tags: magento-2.1, permissions

Running Magento 2.1.6 and after going through many other problems this I hope is the last one. When I attempt to run //update/cron.php in ssh I get permission denied, this don't natter if I am using root or web user access. I've followed the steps as per Magento documentation for directory permissions but problem still remains. I believe this is what is making the cron check fail on readiness check on extension installations.

Is there a way to get this command run?

Comment: Can you write which exact command you run.

Comment: From the Magento root i run /update/cron.php and it brings up the permission denied. Other commands work just fine.

Comment: Try this command from magento root `bin/magento cron:run`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because your file is not executable, even if it was executable anyway it must be run with `php`:

```
[root@server public_html]# update/cron.php
-bash: update/cron.php: Permission denied

[root@server public_html]# php update/cron.php
update-cron: Please check var/log/update.log for execution summary.

[root@server public_html]# su {php_user} -s /bin/bash -c "php update/cron.php"
update-cron: Please check var/log/update.log for execution summary.
```